# EF core 2.2 to EF core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

when I used to use EF 2.2 it rans this code without problems:

```
var resource = locResRepo.GetWhere(i => i.ForApplication.ToLower() == applicationName.ToLower())
            .Where(resourcesConditionExpression)
            .Select(item => new ResourceKeyObject
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                ResourceKey = item.ResourceKey,
                ResourceKeyValues = item.ActualLocalizationTranslation
                .Where(translationConditionExpression)
                .Select(v => new ResourceKeyValues
                {
                    Language = v.Language,
                    KeyValue = v.Value

                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

But now it throws error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression '(MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
    navigation: Navigation: LocalizationResources.ActualLocalizationTranslation,
    subquery: (NavigationExpansionExpression
        Source: DbSet<ActualLocalizationTranslation>
            .Where(a => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(a, "ResourceId"))
        PendingSelector: a => (NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: ActualLocalizationTranslation)
            Expression: a)
    )
        .Where(i => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: LocalizationResources)
            Expression: l), "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>((NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: (EntityReference: LocalizationResources)
            Expression: l), "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(i, "ResourceId")))
    .Where(t => True)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) and so on.....
```

And I really cant realize why..  Or maybe I know something, but i don't know, how to implement it

Comment: You'll find a lot of duplicates about this issue - the problem is the query uses client-side evaluation for parts that can't be translated to SQL. That "feature" was only there to cover for EF Core 1.x missing features. EF Core 2.2 already emits warnings for this, as it's a serious problem. Instead of loading eg just 5 rows, you may be loading 5000000 rows that get filtered on the client. In EF Core 3.0 client-side evaluation was finally disabled

Comment: As for this query, what do `resourcesConditionExpression` and `translationConditionExpression` do? I suspect they make calls to local functions or methods and so can't be converted to SQL. BTW those `ToLower()` calls aren't needed - database collations are usually case-**in**sensitive. Adding that `ToLower()` emits `LOWER()` calls which *prevent* the query optimizer from using indexes

Comment: BTW EF 1.0 to 6.3 didn't have client-side evaluation either. This was only needed for EF 1.x, which couldn't even translate a `.GroupBy` to a proper `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: What is `locResRepo` and what is `GetWhere` ? There's no `GetWhere` in EF, so we don't really know what the code does

Comment: Calling `ToList()` *inside* an EF Query is definitely something that can't be translated, and an excellent example of the N+1 problem  - what this did before, was run 1 extra query for every record in the outer query. For 100 outer rows, you'd get another 100 queries.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* LINQ query you want to run? Some things just can't be expressed as chained calls. If you want to filter included objects for example, you can use `from outer from inner where inner.SomeProp='x'`. EF Core can't filter included objects in the chained call form yet. [Filtered Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#filtered-include) are planned for EF Core 5.0

Comment: From the exception it seems the (missing) expressions contain some unneeded expressions. In SQL, NULL isn't equal to anything, even NULL. The SQL expression `Id=ResourceId` will *never* match NULL Ids, so `EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "Id") != null ` isn't needed. That comparison looks suspiciously like an attempt to JOIN objects that don't have the relations they should, otherwise EF itself would generate a `JOIN` on those columns. And that `Where(t=>true)` wouldn't be generated by EF

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 3.0, EF Core LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client. [learn more: MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

Actually i think your problem may be in i.ForApplication Property if it makes some calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out a solution. Before select must be .ToList() because of EF 3.1 logic

Comment: Actually you do not. You can also do AsEnumerable - so you do not have to make a list if you then do a projecton followed by ToList. Less memory and GC ;)